# Angular: difference when using template or templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, templates, kendo-ui, transclusion

I'm running into a strange issue when using the `template` attribute instead of the `templateUrl` one.

In case of the latter, I can define multiple directives with isolated scope or the `transclude` option on a single element. This works as expected and I don't get any errors.

However when simply copying the template and setting it to `template` in the directive, Angular suddenly starts complaining about multiple directives requesting isolated scope or transclusion on the same element.

See this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BMNOyldd4BQACeaQriL9?p=preview) of mine. It throws an error in the console. However, if you would replace (in scripts.js)

```
template: "<ul kendo-menu k-orientation=\"'vertical'\" k-direction=\"'right'\"></ul>",
```

with

```
templateUrl: 'menu.html'
```

the directive works (try right clicking on the text). The content of the HTML file is **exactly** the same as in the string.

Has anyone got the slightest clue why this inconsistency occurs?

**Edit**: to avoid confusion, I need the transclude option to be there as I'd like to reuse this element and be able to configure what elements to shown on each place it is used separately.

Comment: I'm not familiar with kendo-ui but this template seems to need to be compiled, right?

Comment: @glepretre kendo is only used to render the menu component. The template itself is standard angular, so you don't need to precompile it for it to be able to work. Thanks for taking a look at my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this inconsistency has been fixed in the newer versions of Angular.

We're using `1.0.8` and the correct behaviour (throwing the error when multiple directives require transclusion on the same element) only occurs when using the `template` option. When using the `templateUrl` option, the error is not thrown and the directive works as expected (which still boggles my mind)

Edit: fixed it using the `compile` function and removing the `replace` option. Working example  [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BMNOyldd4BQACeaQriL9?p=preview).

Comment: That was an interesting case. You can now accept your own answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to reproduce the issue, but the problem here actually is `replace: true` in the definition of the `menu` directive.

This means that both `kendo` and the `menu` directive are trying to replace the element in turn. Preserving the `menu` wrapper fixes the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/vGhEVNfz35elCtxXSMxO?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but removing the replace doesn't fix the issue. Angular won't throw an error, but the directive won't work. The strange thing is that when using `templateUrl` instead and keeping the `replace` option, the directive works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem came from `transclude: true` and you also forgot to add your `<li>` elements in your template. If `replace: true` is defined, it will replace the orginal element with its children.

It's working for me, whether using `template` or `templateUrl` : [Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/y6wjMK41KDfsveAcrfQe?p=preview)

**EDIT:**
There's an open issue about this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4357

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need the `transclude` option though, because I'd like to be able to define what should be shown on the menu wherever it is used.

Comment: Hmm. is it solved with Angular latest stable version? I edited my answer to add a link to the open issue ;)

Comment: Thanks for the link! The issue I was having (namely the inconsistency) is fixed though in the latest version.